# How do i read a data from stdout of linux to ajax and get a certain string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, ajax

I have a c program in linux that reads data sent by php using fwrite and output a string in linux.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {cmd:"IN"},
                url: "COMMAND.php",
                success: function(data){

    //Get only this string ">" from the stdout of linux and store it to a variable.

                    }
                });
```

COMMAND.php

```
<?php

if($_POST['cmd']=="IN"){

$fd = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO","w");
fwrite(fd,"IN");
fclose(fd);

}


?>
```

C

```
char buf[255];
while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0 ){ //fd is the opened pipe.

buf[n - 1] = '\0';

if(strcmp(buf,"IN")==0){
            printf("%s\n", "FF0023sff344>fdfslldlf");
          }

    }
```

How do I capture the string "FF0023sff344>fdfslldlf" from linux to ajax and get only the string ">"..?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to run your C program through PHP instead of reading the data from a pipe?

Comment: I can't do that since the c process needs to remain running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a different workflow than what you're doing above. If you need your C process to remain running, you should be opening a bidirectional socket to it.

To do this you'll need to look into making your C program a socket server of some sort.. look into `listen`, `bind`, `accept`, and `select` to get started.

On the PHP side, look into the `sockets` collection of functions.

Alternatively, it can be somewhat easier to make your C program a lightweight http server using something like http://libevent.org/ and then use `curl` on the php side to make requests into it.

Comment: Well I need the c process running. Can I create another pipe? and using the new pipe instead of using stdout I will write on that pipe and let php read that pipe which is much secure i guess.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, named pipes, unix sockets, tcp sockets, light weight http interfaces, whatever.. take your pick as whatever you find the easiest.

Comment: Btw is it okay to create 2 named pipes in linux? so I can have bidirectional communication?

Comment: Sure, although unix domain sockets are canonically more suitable for that sort of thing.